# SQL / MS Access - why isn't this CASE working?

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

I'm writing a query that determines which price to use based on a user-defined date named "USERDATE". When I run this, I get a "syntax error (missing operator) in expression". I want the price selected to be the "UNIT_AMT" which is used later on in the query.

```
SELECT MDDB.NDC, CARRIER.GROUP_ID, [USERDATE] AS USERDATE, MDDB.CODE, CARRIER.DUR_MU_R, CARRIER.FEE_BR, CARRIER.FEE_GR, CARRIER.AWP_BR, CARRIER.AWP_GR, CARRIER.DUR_MU_M, CARRIER.FEE_BM, CARRIER.FEE_GM, CARRIER.AWP_BM, CARRIER.AWP_GM, MDDB.AWP_UNIT_AMT, 

CASE
WHEN USERDATE >= AWP_EFF_DATE THEN AWP_UNIT_AMT
WHEN USERDATE >= AWP_1ST_OLDEST_EFF_DATE AND USERDATE < AWP_EFF_DATE THEN AWP_1ST_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT
WHEN USERDATE >= AWP_2ND_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_1ST_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT THEN AWP_2ND_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT
WHEN USERDATE >= AWP_3RD_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_2ND_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT THEN AWP_3RD_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT
WHEN USERDATE >= AWP_4TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_3RD_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT THEN AWP_4TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT
WHEN USERDATE >= AWP_5TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_4ST_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT THEN AWP_5TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT
ELSE AWP_UNIT_AMT
END AS UNIT_AMT,

((([UNIT_AMT]*[QTY])*((100+[AWP_GR])/100))+[DUR_MU_R]+[FEE_GR]) AS [GR PRICE], 
((([UNIT_AMT]*[QTY])*((100+[AWP_BR])/100))+[DUR_MU_R]+[FEE_BR]) AS [BR PRICE], 
((([UNIT_AMT]*[QTY])*((100+[AWP_GM])/100))+[DUR_MU_M]+[FEE_GM]) AS [GM PRICE], 
((([UNIT_AMT]*[QTY])*((100+[AWP_BM])/100))+[DUR_MU_M]+[FEE_BM]) AS [BM PRICE]
FROM MDDB_MASTER AS MDDB, CARRIER_GROUP AS CARRIER
WHERE (((MDDB.NDC)="41520091574") AND ((CARRIER.GROUP_ID)="709608"));
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: MS Access doesn't have a CASE expression, you need to look at using the [IIF()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) function.

Comment: well that would explain it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Access SQL does not support `CASE ... WHEN`, you could use nested `IIf()` expressions.  However, with so many conditions, that nested `IIf()` would be challenging.  In this case you may find [Switch()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) easier to use.

```
Switch(
    USERDATE >= AWP_EFF_DATE, AWP_UNIT_AMT,
    USERDATE >= AWP_1ST_OLDEST_EFF_DATE AND USERDATE < AWP_EFF_DATE, AWP_1ST_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT,
    USERDATE >= AWP_2ND_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_1ST_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT, AWP_2ND_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT,
    USERDATE >= AWP_3RD_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_2ND_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT, AWP_3RD_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT,
    USERDATE >= AWP_4TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_3RD_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT, AWP_4TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT,
    USERDATE >= AWP_5TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT AND USERDATE < AWP_4ST_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT, AWP_5TH_OLDEST_UNIT_AMT,
    True, AWP_UNIT_AMT
) AS UNIT_AMT
```

Comment: They're all date/time types. I think I just had a typo in `[USERDATE] AS USERDATE`. It seems to be working now :D